# How to Wait for Ajax calls to complete for WEbdriver.io

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to figure out how to make webdriver.io wait until all ajax requests have finished after clicking a button.

Unfortunately the document.readyState is always = 'complete' , and there is nothing "unique" about the webpage except that it has some slightly different data in it.

is there some other way I can test to see if the javascript functions are complete in the page..?

```
    await this.browser.waitUntil(function () {
        return this.execute(function () {
            if (document.readyState === 'complete')
                return true;
        })
    });
```

Comment: This may help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverajax

Comment: Instead of waiting on all/some requests it's better to wait for a specific request to complete. You can use https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/mock.html to spy on particular request and then wait for it to be requested https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio.html#toberequested

Comment: @MikeG. normally we don't care as much about an API being requested, but waiting for it to be completed, regardless of a status. Using your proposal I still don't see how to achieve this

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov can you please clarify your question? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: so all requests go through several steps - initiated, might be redirected, but eventually completed (actual terminology may be different). How I read this question was, the user wants to wait until a request is completed, what you suggested was to wait when it's just initiated. Did I understand it right @MikeG.

Comment: This one works well for the scenario you expect: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio/ It allows waiting for a request to be completed. To be more specific, it waits for a response to be received. You can not just wait for a response but also verify the response itself (body, headers, etc). @SergeyPleshakov

Answer (score 0):

In WDIO 5.x and above, a new third-party plugin called "Intercept Service" was introduced to help with this.

You need to install as dev dependency the service package `wdio-intercept-service` and declare that in wdio.config.js as `services: ['intercept']`

You can set up the interceptor for capturing xhr requests like below.

```
browser.setupInterceptor();  // start capturing xhr requests
```

After the interceptor has been set up, you can declare some expectations about the requests and get those requests using their index (order of declaration of expectation).

```
browser.expectRequest('GET', '/api/foo', 200); // expect GET request to /api/foo with 200 statusCode
var request = browser.getRequest(0);
assert.equal(request.method, 'GET');
assert.equal(request.response.headers['content-length'], '42');
```

You can find more information on their Github page: [Intercept Service](https://github.com/chmanie/wdio-intercept-service)

Comment: doesn't really answer the question but gives a ground to experiment achieving the desired behavior